# Git Publisher during Jenkins build process

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using Git with Jenkins in our project. I want create git tag and then trigger other Jenkins Job. I want the other job to fail the current one in case of failure.
Unfortunately I cannot use Git Publisher in the Build Process neither can I use the strong dependency to the other proces in the Post Build process. I could use the git command in the Batch Script windows directly, but I would like to avoid that. Is there any other way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parameterized trigger plugin[1] as a build step for triggering the other job and pass the git sha1 to the other job instead of using the git tag. You can then still use the Git Publisher to push the tag (if you need it for other purposes).

[1] http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin